# arules - faster mining with given rhs

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I would like to use `arules` to mine association rules with a specific rhs only (say `tomato=1`). I would like to check what the most efficient way to do so is.

The only thing I can find on the web is to set the `appearance` parameter in `apriori()` to

`list(rhs = "tomato=1", default = "lhs")`

Now I believe this exclusion does not shorten the rule mining time, only the writing time. If one sets `maxlen` to 3, for instance, all rules of length 3 (rhs + lhs) fitting the required confidence and support will be explored.

I guess what would be more efficient would be to explore all rules of length 3 containing `tomato=1`. Or to explore all rules of length 2, then calculating their support when `tomato=1` is added, and their confidence.

Is there a way to do something like that with `arules`, or perhaps with another package of its ecosystem?

Comment: Would filtering first on baskets that contain tomato and adjusting support level accordingly work?

Comment: @Gopala: I'm not sure! Writing `a` the antecedent, and `c` my consequent, I would only be able to calculate `P(a/c)`. I don't see how I could get back `P(c/a)` (confidence) and `P(a)` (support) from this. Do you have something specific in mind?